# Svelte unable to import exported type from outer relative folder

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, vite

So I have the following project structure:

```
.
├── src/
│   ├── lib/
│   │   ├── Counter/
│   │   │   └── Counter.svelte
│   │   └── Folder1/
│   │       └── something.ts
│   ├── App.svelte
│   └── main.ts
├── vite.config.ts 
├── tsconfig.json
├── tsconfig.node.json
└── svelte.config.js
```

In `something.ts`, I export an interface:

```
export interface Something{
};
```

And in `Counter.svelte`, I attempt to import it as follows (I even tried removing the `.ts` extension, still got the same problem):

```
<script lang="ts">
 import {Something} from "../Folder1/something.ts"
```

I end up with the following error:

```
"Something" is not exported by "src/lib/Folder1/something.ts", imported by "src/lib/Counter/Counter.svelte".
```

Here are my config files:
`vite.config.ts`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte()],
})
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.svelte"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

`svelte.config.js`:

```
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

export default {
  // Consult https://svelte.dev/docs#compile-time-svelte-preprocess
  // for more information about preprocessors
  preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
}
```

Here is a link to the entire project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ux8acb?file=svelte.config.js

Yes this is based off the vite svetle typescript example.

Comment: I can't reproduce using the link you posted.

Comment: You can either run npm run build in the terminal or check the console on the preview, should be able to see the message

Comment: It should be `import type {Something} from "../Folder1/something.js"`.  Always change the .ts extension to a .js extension.

Comment: Import type worked, and I ended up removing the extension, it wasn't needed.